# C++. Библиотека cmath

Tags: c++

В чём разница между этими двумя функциями:

`pow(cos(x),3)` и `cos(pow(x,3))`

Как эти две записи выглядели бы в математической записи?

Comment: `cos³x` и `cos x³`

Answer (score 5):

Математически это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разница в том, что выполняется первым, что вторым — косинус или возведение в куб...

Comment: Спасибо за столь краткое и понятное объяснение